# Orchard Move Projection To New Zone

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I setup a custom content definition, query and projection to show these content definitions and then setup a Content-[ItemType].Detail.cshtml to fully customize what that item looks like. The problem I'm running into is it puts the detail view for this under `Model.Content` (in Layout.cshtml), but I'd really like to throw the detail view for this content type into a zone called `LargeLeft` instead.

For example, I have the below which is used when the `LargeLeft` zone shows up with one called `SmallRight` (which works really well for its own part):

```
          @* large left bar, small right column *@
          @if (Model.LargeLeft != null && Model.SmallRight != null) {
            <div class="col_12">
              @Zone(Model.LargeLeft)
              @if (Model.SocialMedia != null) {
                @Zone(Model.SocialMedia)
              }                  
            </div>
            <div class="col_4">
              @Zone(Model.SmallRight)
            </div>
          }
```

Since my custom content type just maps to `Model.Content`, the above isn't seen and it gets thrown in here instead:

```
              @if (Model.Content != null) {
              <div class="col_16">
                @Zone(Model.Content)
                @if (Model.SocialMedia != null) {
                  @Zone(Model.SocialMedia)
                }                
              </div>
            }
```

I figure this is something with placement.info, but since I'm not trying to shift individual parts (my designer wanted full HTML control, hence overriding the template) and need to put the whole thing in a specific zone name I'm a bit lost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suppose you could explain your designer that he does have full control over the html...

You can send a shape to an top-level arbitrary zone in placement.info using a slash in front of the zone name.

It is also possible to add a shape to a top-level zone from code using `Layout.ZoneName.Add(yourShape)`.

More about building markup for a type without using placement: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/easy-content-templates-for-orchard-take-2